# How much reputation do I have for each tag?

Tags: discussion

I wonder to know how much I contributed ( reputation ) to the particular tag.

And I found this `Data` `Explorer` called [How much reputation do I have for each tag?](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.salesforce/query/217279/how-much-reputation-do-i-have-for-each-tag#resultSets)

But seems that's not working ...!

Comment: It seems it isn't working for me as well.

Comment: does this not show you what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3762142/rajasimon?tab=tags. Each tag has the number next to it to show you the number of votes you've had against it to show your contribution.

Comment: @Tanner Need to know the reputation I got from the particular tag. From this`62 django × 97` how to know money i earned ?

Comment: @rajasimon `money`

Comment: I believe my career growth based on my SO reputation...! Money comes automatically ... !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That query is using the SalesForce site. You need to switch it to StackOverflow first:

[image]

If I do that I get results for your user id.